# Best way to calculate free space for images that are randomly placed in a defined area

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using HTML's Canvas tag to create a randomly generated word cloud. I am looking for the best (and most efficient) way to calculate where, in a defined area, there is enough whitespace to fit a word. The only way I can think of right now is to have a free list that stores blocks of free space and adjust that as new images are placed on the page.

I have an example generator here: http://pathrazor.com/wordcloud/. However, this example is not yet randomly rotating words, which will add to the complexity of what I'm asking. Collision detection will be added later, if it's not part of the solution to the free space question.

Does anyone have any interesting ideas or has done this before? Any input would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest an algorithm like this:

- Suppose you have a rectangle of empty space.
- Place a word randomly (or pseudo-randomly, or however you like) into that rectangle.
- Imagine the word is wrapped in its own small rectangle. Extend the lines of that rectangle until they reach the borders of the larger container.
- Your remaining free space is now divided into four overlapping rectangles: two vertical ones at the front and back of the word, and two horizontal ones above and below it.
- Store those rectangles in memory.
- The next word you place will overlap either one or two of those rectangles. When it does, divide them further and repeat the process.

You may also find [this question over at SE's game development site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16054/22147) useful.